# roslaunch Problems

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the lauch file

```
<node name="rosplay" pkg="rosbag" type="play" args="~/Desktop/PowRos/Data/User1/pow_freek_1_2011-04-01-14-17-41.bag             --clock"/>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink_laser" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 10"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_imu" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /laser /base_imu 10"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink_camera" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /camera 10"/>

<!-- Start the map server node and specify the map file (*.pgm) and the map resolution in metres/pixel -->
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find amcl_listener)/maps/pow_real_time.yaml"         output="screen"/>

<!--Start the Laser_scan_matcher package, to provide odometry from laser data (ICP)-->
<node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" 
    name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">
    <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>
    <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
</node>

<!-- Start the gmapping node -->
<!--node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen"/-->

<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" respawn="true" output="screen">
    <param name="base_frame_id" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="world"/>
    <param name="global_frame_id" value="map"/>
    <param name="update_min_d" value="0.09"/>   
    <param name="update_min_a" value="0.09"/> 
    <param name="initial_pose_x" value="-1"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_y" value="0"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_a" value="-0.1"/>
    <param name="min_particles" value="6000"/> 
    <param name="max_particles" value="8000"/>
    <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
    <param name="kld_err" value="0.1"/> 
    <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>   
    <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>
</node>

<!--Start the "analyzer_packages"-->
<!-- acml_listener broadcasts markers for the position of the wheelchair, to visualize in Rviz-->
<node pkg="amcl_listener" type="amcl_pose_listener" name="amcl_listener" output="screen"/>
<!-- Object node records minimal ranges from laser, speed_node will record travel speed of wheelchair -->
<node pkg="pow_analyzer" type="object_node" name="object_node" output="screen"/>
<node pkg="pow_analyzer" type="speed_node" name="speed_node" output="screen"/>

<!-- Start an rviz node with a custom configuration for the viewpoint, map_server, trajectory, laser scans, etc -->
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" output="screen" name="rviz" args="-d $(find pow_analyzer)/launch/pow_rviz.vcg/>
```

Ok it was a syntax error. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37810/roslaunch-problems/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-07-03**:
be more specific, can you paste the launch file

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-03**:
ok. already done. Any help?

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-07-03**:
lacks a '<' at beginning, is it only a copy/paste error ?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-03**:
its just copy paste error. First line is  and the last  is . Thats not the problem.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-03**:
Please don't completely overwrite your original question, otherwise answers and questions do not fit together anymore. This is confusing for other users. Instead, open a new question.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-03**:
ok sorry. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your launch file is broken, something is probably malformed. Check the syntax and maybe update your question with the contents of the launch file so that we can check it and provide more help.

**Edit**: Please make sure that you really copy-pasted the complete launch file. It looks pretty broken.

1. The first line should be `<launch>`, not `launch>`
2. The last line needs to be `</launch>` which is completely missing.

**Edit 2**: There is a `"` missing in the last node definition:

```
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" output="screen" name="rviz" args="-d $(find pow_analyzer)/launch/pow_rviz.vcg/>
```

should be

```
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" output="screen" name="rviz" args="-d $(find pow_analyzer)/launch/pow_rviz.vcg" />
```

It helps to use an editor with syntax highlighting such as eclipse, vim or emacs or an actual xml editor to catch this kind of errors.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2